# Importando arquivos DXF e manipulando com Mathematica

Tags: importação, mathematica

Tenho cinco arquivos DXF com várias figuras geométricas.

[image]

São quadrados com uma forma geométrica diferente em cada arquivo DXF ...

Quatro arquivos DXF têm um quadrado com uma forma geométrica diferente em um lado, como mostrado acima.

([DXF1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tg1o1c0r80jn1cl/File1.dxf?dl=1),[DXF2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dbd8a3vc5vhoipj/File2.dxf?dl=1),[DXF3](https://www.dropbox.com/s/orbeqg1rks1szqg/File3.dxf?dl=1),[DXF4](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1uvlw9r0anb30q6/File4.dxf?dl=1),[DXF5](https://www.dropbox.com/s/i4lidjwwec2odsr/File5.dxf?dl=1))

1. É possível juntar esses 5 arquivos?

[image]

2. Alguns arquivos estão na posição errada para serem montados, é possível girá-los?
3. É possível criar um código que possa reconhecer estas geometrias e fazer alguma montagem como esta? A animação é apenas ilustrativa. Foi criado apenas para facilitar a compreensão.

[image: Animated gif]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ReplaceList[MeshPrimitives[#, 2] & /@ meshes, {___,
    {a : Polygon[{___, ap : Repeated[_, {3}], ___}]}, ___,
    {b : Polygon[{___, bp : Repeated[_, {3}], ___}]}, ___} :>
   Module[{err, trans},
    {err, trans} = 
     Chop[FindGeometricTransform[{ap}, Reverse@{bp}, 
       TransformationClass -> "Rigid", Method -> "Linear"], 0.001];
    {Property[a \[DirectedEdge] b, "trans" -> trans],
      Property[b \[DirectedEdge] a, "trans" -> InverseFunction@trans]} /;
     err < 1 && 
      Quiet@Area[
         RegionIntersection[BoundaryDiscretizeRegion@a, 
          BoundaryDiscretizeRegion@TransformedRegion[b, trans]]] < 1]] //
 With[{g = Graph@Flatten@#},
   Graphics[{FaceForm[], EdgeForm@Thick, First@VertexList@g,
     GeometricTransformation[#,
        Composition @@ (PropertyValue[{g, DirectedEdge @@ #}, "trans"] & /@ 
           Partition[FindShortestPath[g, First@VertexList@g, #], 2, 1])] & /@
      Rest@VertexList@g}]] &
```

[image]